# How to change view margins dynamically in "Android Flowlayout"

Tags: android

I have an [Android Flow](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) layout `hash_tag_layout`

```
<org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout

    android:id="@+id/hash_tag_layout"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

</org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout>
```

The problem is I cannot change the margins on dynamically added views.

```
int pixels = convertDensityPixelsToPixels(5);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(0,0,pixels,pixels); //<---<< This line has no effect

TextView tv1 = new TextView(ctx);
tv1.setPadding(pixels,pixels,pixels,pixels); //int left top right bottom
tv1.setBackground(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hash_tag_bubble_format));//drawable
tv1.setText("# Asd");
tv1.setLayoutParams(lp);
layout.addView(tv1);
```

If I change `hash_tag_layout` layout to a regular linear layout, than I get margins!

```
 <LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/hash_tag_layout"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

 </LinearLayout>
```

So I am lead to conlude that [Android Flow](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) layout does not allow me to add margins to views added dynamically!

Any idea how to change the source code or find a way around this? Maybe add a transparent border around the dynamically added views?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to `FlowLayout.LayoutParams`.

[Here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout/issues/70) is an issue discussion on GitHub.

I see that you asked a question 3 years ago, but I have just faced the same problem :)